# Trying to show my child data only once in expandable ListView

Tags: java, android, expandablelistview, expandablelistadapter

I'm trying to show my child data only once in my expandable ListView. But unfortunately it gets shown more than once as you see in the screenshot below:

**EDIT: I have edited my code in `StoreArrayAdapter.java` and in `AllStores.java` . I have also added new screenshots but I still can't manage to show my child data only once. However I do think my code looks clearer now.**

---

In the `getChildView` method I had used the following line of code:

`final Store store = (Store) getChild(groupPosition, groupPosition);`

In the screenshot below you can see that the child gets shown more than once which I don't want. I only want that the child gets shown once.

Link to screenshot: https://i.stack.imgur.com/XBzpQ.png

In the `getChildView` method I had also tried to use the following line of code:

`final Store store = (Store) getChild(groupPosition, childPosition);`

In the screenshot below you can see the ID's from other stores. So that didn't worked out.

Link to screenshot: https://i.stack.imgur.com/zaSC8.png

Below you can see what I had tried. Here is the code:

StoreArrayAdapter.java:

```
public class StoreArrayAdapter extends BaseExpandableListAdapter {
    private List<ParentStore> parentStoresList;
    private Context context;

    public StoreArrayAdapter(Context context, List<ParentStore> parentStoresList) {
        this.context = context;
        this.parentStoresList = parentStoresList;
    }

    @Override
    public View getGroupView(int groupPosition, boolean isExpanded, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
        if (convertView == null) {
            LayoutInflater infalInflater = (LayoutInflater) this.context
                    .getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
            convertView = infalInflater.inflate(R.layout.list_group, null);
        }
        final ParentStore parentStore = (ParentStore) getGroup(groupPosition);
        TextView tvID = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.txtId);
        tvID.setText("Facebook ID: " + parentStore.getChildStoresList().get(groupPosition).getFacebookID());
        TextView tvName = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.txtName);
        tvName.setText(parentStore.getChildStoresList().get(groupPosition).getName());

        return convertView;
    }

    @Override
    public View getChildView(int groupPosition, int childPosition, boolean isLastChild, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
        if (convertView == null) {
            LayoutInflater infalInflater = (LayoutInflater) this.context
                    .getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
            convertView = infalInflater.inflate(R.layout.list_item, null);
        }
        final Store store = (Store) getChild(groupPosition, groupPosition);
        //final Store store = (Store) getChild(groupPosition, childPosition);
        TextView title = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.lblListItem);
        title.setText(store.getFacebookID());

        return convertView;
    }

    //More code..
}
```

Below you can see the whole `StoreArrayAdapter.java` in case you want to see it.

StoreArrayAdapter.java:

Link to the code: http://pastebin.com/dDn5g2dp

In case you want too see how I populated my `parentStoresList` in `AllStores.java`. Then you can see it in the link below.

AllStores.java:

Link to the code: http://pastebin.com/JQ8iWktu

Comment: Something is not right with your `populateList()` method.  I should see two loops, outer one for parent data and inner one for child data.  You only have one loop.  I can't see the parent/child relationship in your data; to me it looks like you are making a child list out of a parent list.

Comment: @krislarson I have edited the implementation of `populateList()`. I think the parent/child relationship looks more clearer now. However I couldn't manage yet to show my child only once. Could you maybe look again at my code, please?

Answer (score 0):

OK in your populate list method, you are adding the stores as position i first of all. This may have some bad consequences when iterating through those store lists again. I would just use the add method with no position.

Edit: As So:

```
private void populateList() throws InterruptedException, ExecutionException, IOException {
    subprises = new StoreService().getSubprises();
    it = subprises.body().iterator();
    parentStore = new ParentStore();
    parentStoresList = new ArrayList<>();
    while(it.hasNext()) {
        Store store = (Store) it.next();
        parentStore.getChildStoresList().clear();
        if (store != null) {
            parentStore.getChildStoresList().add(store);
        }
        parentStoresList.add(parentStore);
    }
    //The logic of putting this outside the loop means they will all the stores will be part of one parent

}
```

And outside when trying to retrieve parent stores and their respective store objects parent stores are always in the group position and child stores will always be in the child position

```
Store theStoreImAfter = parentStoresList.get(groupPosition).getChildStoresList().get(childPosition)
```

EDIT:

Another error I hadn't noticed first time: place the declared parent store outside the loop or clear the results of the previous addition to parent store like so:

```
while (it.hasNext()) {
    parentStore.getChildStoresList().clear();
    //Continue...
}
```

Also when you are inflating your views in getGroupView and getChildView, you aren't binding them to anything. They should be more like:

```
convertView = infalInflater.inflate(R.layout.list_group, parent, false);
convertView = infalInflater.inflate(R.layout.list_item, parent, false);
```

Which can sometimes cause quirks in other code sections

And again I'll edit the code of the populate list method

Comment: Oh and change the getChildView method to call with groupPosition and childPosition properly after that. Before it was probably trying to grab positions 0 and 1 when the items existed at index 59 and 60 (even though it's only 2 items)

Comment: I had tried your code and with the following line of code in my `getChildView` method: `final Store store = (Store) getChild(groupPosition, childPosition);` Unfortunately it didn't worked this was the result: link to screenshot: http://i.imgur.com/k0Vd2mC.png

Comment: Ok check the edit and reimplement populate list and make the few changes in the adapter

Comment: I used `parentStoresList.add` but then I only get to see 1 parent with different children. I want to see different parents. Where 1 parent has a child that holds the same ID of the parent. And when I used `parentStore.getChildStoresList().clear();` then I was getting an error: `java.lang.IndexOutOfBoundsException: Invalid index 1, size is 1`. This was because of this line of code: `tvID.setText("Facebook ID: " + parentStore.getChildStoresList().get(groupPosition).getFacebookID());`

Comment: because the getChildStoresList().get() method is the expansion, it should use childPosition not group position which should refer to the parentStore list

Comment: But I don't have problems with the parent. I have problems with the children of the parent. Basically I want that the 1 and only child that the parent has. That the child is the same `Store` object as the parent.

Comment: You're misunderstanding what I'm saying. I've edited the core explanation to be more correct